git diff a file against the multiple files it was split into
I have a file A on branch old_branch that exists as multiple files A, B, C on a different branch new_branch. I need to merge old_branch into new_branch which would require me to resolve the merge conflicts between old branch A and new branch A. The parts of A that were split off into B and C would not appear as conflicts as they are new files. I would like to compare all changes (A vs A+B+C).
I could git diff A with individual files but a combined diff would be helpful.

Just so I understand the question better; you're looking for a unified diff of A on old_branch with  A, B and C on new_branch?  A unified diff is a format that GNU diff and Git use, but can only represent the differences between two files.  Therefore a 'unified diff' between A and A, B, C doesn't quite make sense.  You may wish to rephrase your question.

Why not combine the files and diff them?
